# Convert csv into json for API request

Tags: python, json, pandas, rest, request

Basically my code will convert a .csv file into a .json and send a request to an API. I think I successfully converted the json, but when I execute it, after a while I get the 422 error. I know converting csv to json is not the best practice, but I need a tabular structure where the end-user can write some information and send the request.

The only scenario the code works perfectly is when I hardcode the json.

Do you have any ideia how to solve those issues ? I'm running out of ideas!

```
import csv 
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

url_auth = 'https://api-gateway.com/token'

payload_auth = {'grant_type': 'client'} 

username = ""
password = ""
  
response_auth = requests.post(url_auth, auth=(username, password), data=payload_auth)
 
data = response_auth.json()

url_prd = 'https://api-gateway.com/api/products'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ data['access_token'],
}

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

def csv_to_json(csvFilePath):
    jsonArray = []
      
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 

        for row in csvReader: 
            jsonArray.append(json.dumps(row,indent=4))
        return jsonArray
    
csvFilePath = filedialog.askopenfilename()

payload = csv_to_json(csvFilePath)

for line in payload:
    response = requests.request("POST", url_prd, headers=headers, data=line)
    
if response.status_code == 200:
    print ('The imports are completed with success')
else:
    print ('The imports failed!')
```

And this is the content:

```
print(response)
<Response [422]>

print(response.content)
b'Reference is missing.'
```

The .csv file is like this:

[image]

And this is the json body in Postman:

```
{
    "Reference":"XXXXX2",
    "products" :[{
        "active": True,
        "skuDistributor": "XX2-DRVDEUB_TEST",
        "designation": "Desctiption filled",
        "smallDescription": "Desctiption filled",
        "bigDescription": "Desctiption filled",
        "price": "700",
        "publicprice": "800"
    }    ]
}
```

Comment: If I print(payload) the format is a little weird...

['{\n    "\\ufeffReference;

Answer (score 1):

Your `csv_to_json` function are returning the JSON string and you are triyng to iterate over it, it's means that every `line` value in your `line in payload`, actually it is a single character not a "request line"

You must change you function for somethin like that:

```py
def csv_to_json(csvFilePath):
    jsonArray = []
      
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 

        for row in csvReader: 
            jsonArray.append(json.dumps(row,indent=4)
        return jsonArray
```

By that way you will iterate over a "lines of requests" like you want.

And I think your request call need to send the `line` not the `payload`,

Comment: Thanks a lot! I fixed the question, however I'm getting response 422. b' Reference is missing.'